# App crashing when using android data-binding on android 8

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

The code work on pre-oreo devices, but Crashlytics saying it crashing on
android 8 devices

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getAppComponent().inject(this);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
    }
```

The stacktrace

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
>   android.view.ViewGroup.getChildCount()' on a null object reference

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.ViewGroup.getChildCount()' on a null object reference
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bindToAddedViews(DataBindingUtil.java:295)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:279)
       at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:261)
       at com.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:59)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: what version of android gradle plugin/databinding are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have similar crashes with exactly the same stacktrace on 8.

Have you tried using:

```
binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.activity, null, false);
setContentView(binding.getRoot());
```

Difference between code above and calling

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...);
```

is that `inflate()` returns a `View` directly which is later passed to `DataBindingUtils::bindToAddedViews`.
In case of `DataBindingUtil.setContentView` the following logic is being used

```
activity.setContentView(layoutId);
View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

and it seems that

```
ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) decorView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

is just `NULL`...

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I get the same crash on Android 8 occasionally.  Hope this will solve the problem.  In case anyone needs: binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.activity_foo, null, false);

Comment: For info, this was reported to google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71885063 . It was closed as "won't fix / not reproducible".  Seems like devs reporting this are seeing it in crash reports (crashlytics, play store console) but have a difficult time reproducing it. In our app, it's our top crash report.

Comment: Does anybody have an idea what could cause `android.R.id.content` to be absent? After a few hours of looking through AOSP source code to get ideas on how to reproduce this, I still haven't been able to reproduce it. However, it's our top reported crash, so many users are seeing it.